Vertical scaling doesn't work properly in React Native
I don't understand how to make my React Native app 100% responsive.
I've looked into it, but overall I haven't found anything better than using Flexbox or scaling functions like these:
const horizontalScale = (size) => (Dimensions.get('window').width / guidelineBaseWidth) * size;
const verticalScale = (size) => (Dimensions.get('window').height / guidelineBaseHeight) * size;

The issue with these functions (especially verticalScale) is that, although the size adjusts relatively well to my screen and the proportion/distance between elements is preserved, it feels like the screen is too small or that verticalScale is scaling relative to a screen larger than the actual device size. To illustrate, I'm sending a screenshot with the dimensions of guidelineBaseHeight and guidelineBaseWidth (393x793), where everything displays as I want, and another on a smaller device (360x616). If anyone has an idea on how to fix this issue, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!
screen_393x793
screen_360x616
here is the code of the page on the screenshots : https://paste.mozilla.org/83vUVXsR
